# How to show percentage measure in a card visual?

Tags: powerbi

Sample data:

```
+----------+------------+----------+-----------+
| PersonID |    Date    |   Booked |    Picked |
+----------+------------+----------+-----------+
|        1 | 1 Jan 2023 |      100 |       100 |
|        2 | 1 Jan 2023 |       40 |        30 |
|        3 | 1 Jan 2023 |       20 |        40 |
|        1 | 2 Jan 2023 |       50 |        80 |
|        2 | 2 Jan 2023 |       70 |        70 |
|        3 | 2 Jan 2023 |       60 |        40 |
+----------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

I have a measure as follows:

Performance % = DIVIDE(IF(Calls[Picked]>Calls[Booked],Calls[Booked],Called[Picked]),Calls[Booked])

I have formatted this as %

When I place this in a table visual then I get a % value.

But when I place it into a card visual then it forces me to choose sum/min/max/...

1. What is the way to display the value of a measure in a card visual?
2. How to iterate over each row to calculate the percentage value - for example - there is no DIVIDEX in dax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with a **Measure** as below-

```
Performance % = 
DIVIDE(
    IF(
        SUM(Calls[Picked])>SUM(Calls[Booked]),
        SUM(Calls[Booked]),
        SUM(Calls[Picked])
    ),
    SUM(Calls[Booked])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Your formula is DIVIDE(2,1); where as mine is using columns - try that way please.

Comment: Oh! you can not do that as Card always expect 1 single value. If you have a measure that generates % per row, you can not add that to the Card visual. You must need to apply an aggregation.

Comment: So what is the solution to display the % value in a card visual? or any other visual I can use for this please to just display the value of measure?

Comment: Just apply an aggregation. May be average will keep the same value if you only have 1 row in the dataset.

Comment: Measure is effectively 1 row? So does it matter if I use avg/sum/min/max?

Comment: You are right. But when setting that measure in CARD, you must calculate a single value from the output from 10 Rows (for example). Now, if they are different in 10 rows and aggregation will not populate a correct value, you can not use that measure in a CARD.

Comment: Another thing, your measure contains no aggregation in it. If you have a measure with aggregation like- SUM(column1+Column2), you can then set that into a CARD.

Comment: When I place the measure into card visual, then measure will calculate the value considering all 10 rows.. So what is the harm in using avg/sum/min/max?

Comment: What is you expected output in card from the above given sample data?

Comment: Check my updated answer to get some clue :)

Comment: So what aggregation is the card visual using? Should you use min or max the value would remain the same.

Comment: No MIN/MAX will take MIN from all rows when you use that in the CARD. But in row level, MIN/MAX/SUM/AVG all same.